# div with background-repeat: no-repeat; repeats

Tags: css

I've got a div with a CSS which states `background-repeat: no-repeat;`, but if the div is bigger then the image, the image starts to repeat itself.

Any ideas, suggestions etc are welcome. Thank you

```
.background-image{
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;    
    background-size: 1700px, 819px; 
    background: url('../assets/kafa.jpg');  
    border: 0px;
    background-position: -1050px -550px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ohymeft0/

Comment: The issue here is that you're mixing shorthand (`background`) and longhand (`background-repeat`) properties. The shorthand property `background` overrides the values of all longhand properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `background` to `background-image` and that should work

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `background` shorthand property which sets many values, including `background-repeat`. Either change `background` to `background-image`, or place your `background-repeat` property after the `background` rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.background-image{
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;    
    background: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/20/18/03/cat-2083492__340.jpg') no-repeat;   
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

As @chriskirknielsen said, your overriding your properties. This solves that.

Answer (score 0):

The property `background` is shorthand for several CSS background properties (see
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background).

Where you've set that after `background-repeat: no-repeat` it overrides the previous property and uses its default repeat style.

If you replace `background: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/20/18/03/cat-2083492__340.jpg');` in your example with `background-image` (see the amended code snippet below) it should give the result you're expecting.

```css
.background-image {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
  background-size: 1700px, 819px;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/20/18/03/cat-2083492__340.jpg');
  border: 0px;
  background-position: -1050px -550px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-image"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  .background-image{ 
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
    background: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/20/18/03/cat-2083492__340.jpg')    no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Try to add a explaination to your awnsers, while the code might work it would be better to explain why this code works.